# Tooltip is not working for Nested repeated control in C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 telephone lines with radio button. On the basis of radio button , i am showing the details for the line details in repeater control. On page load 1st radio button is selected & tool-tip( is working. I added the tool tip on ITEM_databound under C# on code behind. 
When i select 2nd radio button, the repeater control updated. When i hover the mouse tool tip stopped working. I inspect the element the tool-tip class is there.

In ASp.net(C#), code behind :

```
Label1.Style.Add("Color", "Red");
Label1.CssClass = "normal_tooltip";
Label1.Attributes.Add("original-title", "The product is not available.");
```

in asp:

```
Label1.Attributes.Add("tipsy-gravity", "s");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your radio is causing a postback probably within an update panel.  If this is the case you will have to re-init the js that handles your tooltip once you cause a postback.  This can be done from code behind with script manager.

```
string strScript = null;
strScript = "alert('" + sInfo + "');";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanelID, UpdatePanelID.GetType, "ShowInfo", strScript, true);
```

Comment: Yes u r correct, radio button is causing postback. WE tried to use jquery even bt no luck here...i am adding the style & class to on item databound of repeated control... can u share some example...